# Combo boxes in PyQt6 all depending on each other

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox, pyqt6

I am working with PyQt6 and need to create a variable number of combo boxes. Each of these boxes should have their items changed based on the value selected in every other box. The boxes cannot have the same value selected except for the default value of "None". When one box's value changes, the previous value should appear in all other boxes. I have some code that seems to work, but would like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this.

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, \
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QComboBox
import sys

input_row_layout = []
original_list = ["None", "1", "2", "3"]
previous = {"Box0":"None", "Box1":"None", "Box2":"None"}

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("ComboBoxes")
        boxes = ["Box1", "Box2", "Box3"]
        input_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            input_row_layout.append(QVBoxLayout())
            relay_label = QLabel("Box %d"%(i + 1))
            input_row_layout[i].addWidget(relay_label)
            relay = QComboBox()
            input_row_layout[i].addWidget(relay)
            relay.setObjectName("Box%d"%i)
            relay.addItems(original_list)
            relay.activated.connect(self.onComboBoxChanged)
            input_layout.addLayout(input_row_layout[i])
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(input_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
  

    def onComboBoxChanged(self):
        sendingCombo = self.sender()
        sendingComboName = sendingCombo.objectName()
        sendingComboValue = sendingCombo.currentText()
        for i in range(len(input_row_layout)):
            # Looping through all boxes
            currentBox = input_row_layout[i].itemAt(1).widget()    # The i-th box
            if currentBox.objectName() != sendingComboName:    # Skip the sending box
                current_value = currentBox.currentText()    # Current value for the i-th box
                current_list = [currentBox.itemText(j) for j in range(currentBox.count())]    # All items in the i-th box
                prev_index = original_list.index(previous[sendingComboName])
                if sendingComboValue != previous[sendingComboName]:
                    if prev_index > 0:
                        while original_list[prev_index] not in current_list:  # Ensuring the current_list has the same order as original_list
                            prev_index -=1
                        a = original_list[prev_index]
                        current_list.insert(current_list.index(a) + 1, previous[sendingComboName])
                            
                    if sendingComboValue != "None":
                        current_list.remove(sendingComboValue)    # Removes the newly selected value from other boxes
                    currentBox.clear()
                    currentBox.addItems(current_list)
                    current_index = currentBox.findText(current_value)
                    currentBox.setCurrentIndex(current_index)
        previous[sendingComboName] = sendingComboValue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "items changed based on the value selected in every other box"? We cannot just assume the logic of your code, as it may be faulty, we need to understand the criteria used to change every item of each checkbox and the selected item for it.

Comment: @musicamante I can not have the same value selected in two, or more, boxes at the same time, unless it's the value "None". A value selected in one box should not be selectable in any other box, i.e. that value must be removed from all other boxes itemslists. If one box changes its selected value, that box previous value should be selectable from all boxes, hence must that value be inserted in all other boxes itemslists.

Comment: Do al  the boxes have the same items, or can boxes have unique values?

Comment: All boxes initializes with the same list of values and the selected value is "None" in every box. I couldn't get it to work without global variables at first but now I do so I can live with my code now though it probably could be improved.

Comment: I have a similar situation in a project of mine: a couple of comboboxes that can't have a item in the list when it selected in one of the others. I do that by setting custom models for the boxes. There's one source model with the data and a sortfilterproxymodel per box. The source model keeps track of the last made selection and the proxymodels use `filterAcceptsRow` to filter out that value from the other boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit too much convoluted than it could need.

If you are completely sure that each item is unique, you could just filter out the existing items in any list (excluding that of the current); otherwise, if there could be duplicate items, then it's not reliable, because `findText()` only matches the first occurrence.

My suggestion is to always use logical indexes for both the item lists *and* the combo boxes. In this way, the filtering and box filling will always be reliable, no matter the text contents.

This involves associating a logical index to the original items, which allows to track the current index in the original list, even if the combo does not have all the items.

This is also made easier by using the second argument of [`addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#addItem): we add each item with the associated index in the original list:

```py
            for idx, item in enumerate(original_list):
                relay.addItem(item, idx)
```

Then, this is what happens when any combo changes:

1. create new *enumerated* lists for each combo box;
2. get the index of the original list of the currently selected item as inserted before (using [`currentData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop)) for each combobox;
3. if *any* index is greater than 0 (so, it's not `"None"`):

   4. we create a list of any of those indexes greater than 0; that list will also be sorted *and* reversed, and will be used to filter out items in the lists;
   5. we iterate through the enumerated lists (see point 1) *and* the current index of each combo (point 2);
   6. for each iteration we cycle through the reversed list (point 4) and remove the items if their index is different from the current; the reversed list is necessary to keep the correct removal order;

---

7. finally, and in any case, we iterate through the comboboxes, the enumerated lists we just filtered and the "current" indexes, we block signals for the combo to avoid recursion, clear it, add the filtered lists (using `addItem()` as above) and, if the logical index is the same of the current, we make item as the actual current one of the combo;

Here is the code:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ComboBoxes")

        container = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        input_layout = QHBoxLayout(container)

        self.combos = []
        for i in range(3):
            relay = QComboBox()
            self.combos.append(relay)
            for idx, item in enumerate(original_list):
                relay.addItem(item, idx)

            relay.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onComboBoxChanged)

            comboLayout = QVBoxLayout()
            comboLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Box %d" % (i + 1)))
            comboLayout.addWidget(relay)
            input_layout.addLayout(comboLayout)
  

    def onComboBoxChanged(self):
        boxLists = [list(enumerate(original_list)) for i in range(len(self.combos))]
        currentIndexes = []
        for combo in self.combos:
            currentIndexes.append(combo.currentData())

        if any(currentIndexes):
            toFilter = sorted(set([v for v in currentIndexes if v]), reverse=True)
            for boxList, current in zip(boxLists, currentIndexes):
                for index in toFilter:
                    if index != current:
                        boxList.pop(index)

        for combo, boxList, current in zip(self.combos, boxLists, currentIndexes):
            with QSignalBlocker(combo):
                combo.clear()
                for i, (idx, item) in enumerate(boxList):
                    combo.addItem(item, idx)
                    if idx == current:
                        combo.setCurrentIndex(i)
```

Note that I used `currentIndexChanged` (which requires signal blocking) as it is more appropriate, because `activated` is also emitted when the choice is not changed, which would unnecessarily call the connected function.